# MATLAB: Huge performance issues when running a nested for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ode45

I am solving a problem that involves multiple combinations of spring mass damper systems. When I run a single for loop, the code runs perfectly, however the nested for loops will not run. I am not receiving any errors. The code is just incapable of solving the ode45 function. Any tips on how I can remedy this issue?

```
%% Project Parameters
%{
    Isolation mats use 5% of the floor area (A_mat=.05A)
%}

clc,clear

time=linspace(0,3,5001);            %Time in seconds
A = (8*12*.0254)^2;                 %Area of floor
A_mat = .05*A;                      %Area of mat
m_plywood = (1200)*(A)*(3*.0254);   %Mass of plywood
m = 550/9.81;                       %Mass of runner
m0 = 1e-3*min([m_plywood m]);       %Mass seperating isolation mats

m=158.757; % kg of person and weight
% impact velocity is 4.89 m/s for 200 lb object dropped from 48 inches
% by impulse momentum theorem, we have ( 90.7 kg )*( 4.89 m/s) = ( M=158.757 kg ) * ( inital velocity )
% solving for initial velocity, we get 2.7937 m/s
xdot0=90.7*4.89/158.757; % 2.7937 m/s initial velocity of floor

%Parameters for rubber mat
m_rubber = (1800)*A*(1*.0254);                      %Rubber mat mass
k_rubber = (12e6)*A/(1*.0254);                      %Rubber mat stiffness
zeta_rubber = .08;                                  %Rubber mat damping ratio
c_rubber = zeta_rubber*2*sqrt(k_rubber*m_rubber);   %Rubber mat damping coefficient

%Parameters for SPX
m_spx = (1200)*A_mat*(1*.0254);           %SPX mat mass
k_spx = (1e6)*A/(1*.0254);                %SPX mat stiffness
zeta_spx = .08;                           %SPX mat damping ratio
c_spx = zeta_spx*2*sqrt(k_spx*m_spx);     %SPX mat damping coefficient

%Parameters for DMP
m_dmp = (1500)*A_mat*(1*.0254);           %DMP mat mass
k_dmp = (10e6)*A/(1*.0254);               %DMP mat stiffness
zeta_dmp = .22;                           %DMP mat damping ratio
c_dmp = zeta_dmp*2*sqrt(k_dmp*m_dmp);     %DMP mat damping coefficient

%Parameters for FRX
m_frx = (1800)*A_mat*(1*.0254);           %FRX mat mass
k_frx = (8e6)*A/(1*.0254);                %FRX mat stiffness
zeta_frx = .15;                           %FRX mat damping ratio
c_frx = zeta_frx*2*sqrt(k_frx*m_frx);     %FRX mat damping coefficient

%Parameters for BPX
m_bpx = (1200)*A_mat*(1*.0254);           %BPX mat mass
k_bpx = (6e6)*A/(1*.0254);                %BPX mat stiffness
zeta_bpx = .06;                           %BPX mat damping ratio
c_bpx = zeta_bpx*2*sqrt(k_bpx*m_bpx);     %BPX mat damping coefficient

k = [k_bpx, k_frx, k_dmp, k_spx]';        %Setting stiffness vector to loop through
c = [c_bpx, c_frx, c_dmp, c_spx]';        %Setting damping vector to loop through

%% Dynamic System Modeling, Scenario 1: 1 inch of ioslation mats
clc
for j = 1:length(k)
    [t,y1]=ode45(@(t,z)[z(2); ...
        k_rubber/m_plywood*z(3)+c_rubber/m_plywood*z(4)-(c_rubber+c(j))/m_plywood*z(2)-(k_rubber+k(j))/m_plywood*z(1); ...
        z(4); ...
        c_rubber/m*z(2)+k_rubber/m*z(1)-c_rubber/m*z(4)-k_rubber/m*z(3)],time,[0;xdot0;0;0]);
end


%% Dynamic System Modeling, Scenario 2: 2 inches of isolation mats

clc
for j = 1:length(k)
   for jj = 1:length(k)
        [t,y2]=ode45(@(t,z)[z(2); ...
            c(jj)/m0*z(4)+k(jj)/m0*z(3)-(c(jj)+c(j))/m0*z(2)-(k(jj)+k(j))/m0*z(2); ...
            z(4); ...
            c_rubber/m_plywood*z(6)+k_rubber/m_plywood*z(5)-(c_rubber+c(jj))/m_plywood*z(4)-(k_rubber+k(jj))/m_plywood*z(3); ...
            z(6); ...
            c_rubber/m*z(4)+k_rubber/m*z(3)-c_rubber/m*z(6)-k_rubber/m*z(5); ...
            ],[0:15],[0;xdot0;0;0;0;0]);
    end
end

%% Dynamic System Modeling, Scenario 3: 3 inches of isolation mats
clc
for j = 1:length(k)
    for jj = 1:length(k)
        for jjj = 1:length(k)
            [t,y3]=ode45(@(t,z)[z(2); ...
                c(jj)/m0*z(4)+k(jj)/m0*z(3)-(c(jj)+c(j))/m0*z(2)-(k(jj)+k(j))/m0*z(1); ...
                z(4); ...
                c(jjj)/m0*z(6)+k(jjj)/m0*z(5)-(c(jjj)+c(jj))/m0*z(4)-(k(jjj)+k(jj))/m0*z(3); ...
                z(6); ...
                c_rubber/m_plywood*z(8)+k_rubber/m_plywood*z(7)-(c_rubber+c(jjj))/m_plywood*z(6)-(k_rubber+k(jjj))/m_plywood; ...
                z(8); ...
                c_rubber/m*z(6)+k_rubber/m*z(5)-c_rubber/m*z(8)-k_rubber/m*z(7); ...
                ],time,[0;xdot0;0;0;0;0;0;0]);
        end
    end
```

Comment: “Will not run” or just takes forever to run? Have you tried running every case on it’s own outside of the double `for` loop or just one of them? The ability of `ode45` to integrate a system is dependent on the parameters – in this case likely due to a given parametrization’s stiffness. What happens if you use `ode15s` instead?

Comment: In your loops you overwrite the output variables every iteration. Might was well run only the last iteration, the results of all other iterations are discarded.